# Is there a way to load up a web browser in the augmented reality magic leap and parse the data in this browser into another magic leap app?

Tags: augmented-reality, magic-leap

Is there a way to launch a AR web browser with the magic leap AR dev kit? And then parse data from this web browser via an API into another application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exokit ( https://webmr.io ) can solve your problem.

This project enables developers to build XR experiences using the same code that runs on the web. Exokit engine is written on top of Node and emulates a web browser, providing native hooks for WebGL, WebXR, WebAudio, and other APIs used in immersive experiences.

We recently released a [Magic Leap API](https://docs.webmr.io/docs/MagicLeapAPI.html) which has led to [experiments on the Magic Leap via Exokit](https://webmr.io/showcase/) like [shared meshing between the Magic Leap One and HTC Vive](https://twitter.com/webmixedreality/status/1039687427638538240).

Feel free to reach out on [Discord](https://discord.gg/Apk6cZN) or [Slack](https://join.slack.com/t/exokit/shared_invite/enQtNDI3NjcxNzYwMDIxLWU2NmFmOTEzMzk4NWNiYjRhMjVkYzcyNjg5YjUyMzZkYWM1ZGI4M2IwYWZiMjNlMTJjMDlkM2U3Y2JiNTc2M2Q) to help get set up with the [Magic Leap One](https://github.com/webmixedreality/exokit#run-magic-leap-device).

Answer (score 1):

These links should provide your answer. But, yes what Exokit has posted is indeed the correct response.

[Exokit On GitHub](https://github.com/webmixedreality/exokit/)

[Exokit On The Docs Site](https://docs.webmr.io/)

[Exokit On WebMixedReality](https://webmr.io/)

[Avaer Kazmer With Nick On Exokit, Multi-Player Experience](https://www.reddit.com/r/magicleap/comments/9f4ark/joining_a_ml_user_from_anywhere_from_vr_or/)